# JSTL: Unable to populate where clause param value

Tags: sql, jstl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setpid()
{
    var s1val=document.getElementById('s1').value;
    document.getElementById('t1').value=s1val;
    var para=document.getElementById('t1').value;
    if(para)
    {
          <sql:query var="prod1_query">
        SELECT DISTINCT PROD_ID FROM  "CH3TAN"."PRODUCT" WHERE CUST_ID=?
        <sql:param value="${param.para}"/> // here is the problem
        </sql:query>
    }
}
</script>
```

My problem is s2 select tag will be populated after selecting in s1 select.

But I'm unable to set the `param` value to the where clause.
    `var para` is getting the value.

Comment: `para` lives in the browser. The SQL is executed on the server. You need to somehow get `para` back to the server.

Comment: How to send data to server without using form or submit button.

Comment: Without using a form or submit, you'd use Ajax.

Comment: Shouldn't you place the sql tag within jstl and not js function?

Comment: @MariaIoannidou : i tried placing sql tag within jstl and as well as within js function. Ultimatly the value will b set after submitting the form and form submitting take time which i don't want.

Comment: @Thilo : i goggle about ajax but it retrieve all the data from the table. I want to retrieve a column, can you post some examples or link.